# How to attach click listener on pop up image

Tags: reactjs, lightgallery

[image]

I want to do something if the image got clicked like redirect user to another page, or is there a way to wrap the pop up image with `<a>` tag?

I can't simply just wrap the `<img>` with `<a>` because as far as I know the pop up is created on the fly, so I need to tell the lightgalery to include `<a>` wrapper when they creating the pop up. but I dont know how...

Answer (score -1):

the easiest way to do this is to use the `<a>` tag and wrap you image.

```
<a href="{src}">
    <img src="img.jpg" />
</a>
```

of course this is only to redirect or send to another part of the page. If you want to do something like play a sound or trigger an animation you would do something else like.

```
<Component onClick={() => handleClick()}>
    <img src="img.jpg">
</Component>
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: I can't simply do that

Comment: please elaborate on what it is you cant do? can you provide a code sandbox?

Comment: I add a bit explanation on my question

Comment: can you share some code?

Answer (score -1):

For this you need to create a router file where you will able to redirect your output wherever you want on click.

If its not answer please say in some more descriptive way .

Or `<a href="..." target="_blank"> <img src="..." /> </a>`

This is even absolutely correct way.

```js
import React from "react"
import {Navigate} from 'react-router-dom'
function App(){
  const handleNavigate=()=>{
    navigate("/whatever")
  }
  return
  <div onClick={()=>handleNavigate()}>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKSCu.jpg" alt="s" />
  </div>
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your effort, May be I should remove the react tag on this question, this is not particularly about react alone, but mostly about how to work with LightGallery library. One should know not only react but the other one too to be able to answer this question